# Chakra UI modal window bug in Chorme

Tags: google-chrome, safari, textarea, react-typescript, chakra-ui

I have bug on chrome with text area in modal Chakra-UI. On Firefox it works fine, but safari and chrome not working right.

[Safari_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwZNs.png)

```
<ModalContent css="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: -webkit-fill-available" my="0.75em">
  <ModalHeader>
    {task.taskType} ({task.status})
  </ModalHeader>
  <ModalCloseButton />
  <ModalBody display="flex">
          <Textarea
              fontFamily="monospace"
              value={getUnescapedJSON(inputData)}
              isReadOnly
              id="t_input"
              variant="filled"
              minH={200}
            />
              .
              .
              .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :D
-webkit-fill-available maybe not working on chrome so I erased it and it's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).